# Terminal and shell, defining a shorthand for: find with grep and replace with sed

Tags: bash, sed, terminal, grep

So i trying to create my bash file that traverses through the current directory and replaces all occurrences of a string with a new one.

I have create this line and this works perfectly when running directly from Terminal but when its in a .sh file, it errors out.

```
cmd_sr="grep -rl 'REPLACESTRING' ./ | xargs sed -i '.bak' 's/REPLACESTRING/REPLACED/g'"`
```

And then executed the above line with `$cmd_sr` on the next line.

The following errors are shown.

```
grep: |: No such file or directory
grep: xargs: No such file or directory
grep: sed: No such file or directory
grep: '.bak': No such file or directory
grep: 's/REPLACESTRING/REPLACED/g': No such file or directory
```

Now I think I understand why this is happening, grep is trying to use the parameters after the './' as files, but obviously fails.

Hoping someone could point out the obvious error as im struggling to locate the issue.

=== EDIT ===

After some updates to the code and replacing it as a function... I have this

```
function sr {
    printf "Checking for $1 to replace with $2\n"
    grep -rl '%%APP_$1%%' ./ | xargs sed -i '.bak' 's/%%APP_$1%%/$2/g'
}
```

This function is called from a loop that does loops through a list of strings to replace in the directory structure.

```
sr TITLE $title
```

Where $title is derived from the loop. As i need to check for a number of strings like `%%APP_xxxx%%` a function was the easier to implement.

However with the updates made, I do not get an error now, but I also do not get an string replacements. Is it possible to view an output to see the files that it is looping through or perhaps finding these strings in?

Comment: Simply say: `grep -rl 'REPLACESTRING' ./ | xargs sed -i '.bak' 's/REPLACESTRING/REPLACED/g'` instead of _assigning_ the command to a string and then trying to execute it.

Comment: Word splitting happens before variable expansion. Try `eval`, but be careful.

Comment: Do not assign a command to a string. Commands are code, strings are data, don't mix them, and don't do `eval` until attaining an enlightened guru status. If you want to build a complex command, use a *function*.

Answer (score 2):

```
cmd_sr() { grep -rl 'REPLACESTRING' ./ | xargs sed -i '.bak' 's/REPLACESTRING/REPLACED/g' ; }
```

Then use `cmd_sr` instead of `$cmd_sr`

Answer (score 1):

Your string doesn't contain one command but two piped commands. It is lot of things going behind in shell. Shell firs makes pipe, forks subprocess, redirects stdin in this subprocess to this pipe and then `exec` to `xargs`. Then in main process forks another subprocess, redirects stdout of this subprocess to the pipe and `exec` to grep. When you place `$cmd_sr` as line in script shell doesn't have any clue there is `|` in this command but treates it as one command, so fork and exec to this command. Make function instead.

```
cmd_sr() {
    grep -rl 'REPLACESTRING' . |
        xargs sed -i '.bak' 's/REPLACESTRING/REPLACED/g'
}
cmd_sr
```

But personally I would prefer

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'REPLACESTRING' {} \; -exec sed -i '.bak' 's/REPLACESTRING/REPLACED/g' {} +
```

Comment: Ok, you have explained my solution *after* I posted. Please make two up to any other solution of mine in another question, report back here, and I will delete my solution.

Comment: -execdir is better than -exec when other processes are sharing filesystem.

Comment: @user2987828: Sorry, I have started writing mine answer before you posted yours. Longer answer usually takes some time.

Comment: at `-exec` vs `execdir`, I'm more concerned by file-names containing spaces than security. Anyway, it can be used as well.